# Android SQLite Insert working, Query not working

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my first time posting to this site so hopefully it will be a positive experience.  I have an Android SQLite/ContentProvider problem that I have been beating my head against the wall for over the past 3 hours.  Below is the ContentProvider code:

```
public class IncidentProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;
private static final HashMap<String, String> projectionMap;
private static final int INCIDENTS = 1;

public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.test.providers.IncidentsProvider";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "incidents";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getString(R.string.database_name), null, Integer.parseInt(context.getString(R.string.database_version)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                + Incidents.INCIDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                + Incidents.NAME + " VARCHAR(30),"
                + Incidents.CREATE_TIME + " LONG," 
                + Incidents.LAST_UPDATE + " LONG," 
                + Incidents.IS_ACTIVE + " VARCHAR(30)" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

/**
 * Delete a row from the database
 */
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCIDENTS:
            count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    db.close();
    return count;
}

/**
 * Return the content type managed by this ContentProvider
 */
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCIDENTS:
            return Incidents.CONTENT_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN URI " + uri);
    }
}

/**
 * Insert new content into a row in the database
 */
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    if(sUriMatcher.match(uri) != INCIDENTS) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN URI " + uri);

    ContentValues values;
    if(initialValues != null) {
        values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
    } else {
        values = new ContentValues();
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, Incidents.NAME, values);

    if(rowId > 0) {
        Uri incidentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Incidents.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(incidentUri, null);
        db.close();
        return incidentUri;
    }
    db.close();
    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

/**
 * Called when creating this ContentProvider
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return false;
}

/**
 * Called when making a query to this content provider
 */
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCIDENTS:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
            qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN URI " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    db.close();
    return c;
}

/**
 * Called when updating a row through this content provider
 */
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
        String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCIDENTS:
            count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    db.close();
    return count;
}

static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME, INCIDENTS);

    projectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    projectionMap.put(Incidents.INCIDENT_ID, Incidents.INCIDENT_ID);
    projectionMap.put(Incidents.NAME, Incidents.NAME);
    projectionMap.put(Incidents.CREATE_TIME, Incidents.CREATE_TIME);
    projectionMap.put(Incidents.LAST_UPDATE, Incidents.LAST_UPDATE);
    projectionMap.put(Incidents.IS_ACTIVE, Incidents.IS_ACTIVE);
}
```

}

I also wrote a db helper class to make it easy to interact with the ContentProvider.  2 example DBHelper methods are as follows (1 to insert, 1 to query).

```
    /**
     *  Adds a new incident to the database
     **/
 public void addNewIncident(ContentResolver contentResolver, Incident incident) {
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(Incidents.NAME, incident.getName());
  contentValues.put(Incidents.CREATE_TIME, incident.getCreateTime());
  contentValues.put(Incidents.LAST_UPDATE, incident.getLastUpdate());
  contentValues.put(Incidents.IS_ACTIVE, incident.isActive()?"true":"false");

  contentResolver.insert(Incidents.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

 } 

    /**
     * Retrieves all incidents from the database
     **/
    public ArrayList<Incident> getIncidents(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
  Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Incidents.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  ArrayList<Incident> returnList = new ArrayList<Incident>();

  if(c!=null && c.moveToNext()) {
   for(int i=0; i<c.getCount(); i++) {
    c.moveToPosition(i);
    Incident incident = new Incident(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Incidents.NAME)));
    incident.setCreateTime(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Incidents.CREATE_TIME)));
    incident.setLastUpdate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Incidents.LAST_UPDATE)));
    incident.setActive(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Incidents.IS_ACTIVE)).equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    returnList.add(incident);
   }
   c.close();
  }

  return returnList;
 }
```

Okay!  So here is my problem.  I can insert into the database without any problems! If I query the database through adb shell I can see all of the records that are being inserted.  When I query using SQLiteQueryBuilder, or SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery, or any other method of querying, the returned cursor comes back with -1.  Does not matter if I query for an individual record, or query the entire database.  The query still comes back -1.

Any ideas?  Am I missing something incredibly simple?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help a frustrated individual!

UPDATE:

Below is example code for inserting (that works), and querying (that doesn't work)

```
/** 
 * Following db insert works
 */
IncidentsDB db = IncidentsDB.getInstance(); 
workingIncident.setLastUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis());     // isActive, and createTime set in constructor
db.addNewIncident(this.getContentResolver(), workingIncident);

/**
 * Following db queries do not work, cursor ends up with mCount=-1 
 */
 Cursor c = IncidentsDB.getInstance().getIncidents(this.getContentResolver());
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit. First of all, I would recommand you to download SQLite Database Browser to test your queries. This will help you ensuring that the queries you put in rawQuery are working on the database.(You can export the databases of your application from the DDMS perspective in Eclipse : File explorer Data/data/name.of.you.package/databases/nameOfTheDatabase.db

Comment: Can you post an example of the criteria used in both the builder and raw queries?

Comment: Have you tried contentResolver.rawQuery("select * from "+Incidents.CONTENT_URI, null);?

Comment: Wow!  You guys respond quickly!  Thanks so much for the help. 
 Sephy, thanks for the suggestion.  I have done exactly as you said and ran the following raw query:  select isActive, create_time, last_update, _id, name FROM incidents; Which gives desired results (listing of all incidents).

Comment: Quintin, here is an example of the insert that is working.


Incident workingIncident = new Incident("test incident"); 
IncidentsDB db = IncidentsDB.getInstance();  workingIncident.setLastUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis());  db.addNewIncident(this.getContentResolver(), workingIncident);

Here is an example of the query that is not working:

IncidentsDB.getInstance().getIncidents(this.getContentResolver());

Comment: Sephy, appears contentResolver does not have a rawQuery method.

Answer (score 3):

Well, looks like I fixed it.  Turns out it is better to close the database in the finalize method as opposed to opening and closing in the each of the delete, insert, query, and update methods like I have in the posted code above.  Here is the code snippet for those of you that run into this problem like I did:

```
// add SQLiteDatabase member variable to content provider
private SQLiteDatabase db;

/**
 * Delete a row from the database
 */
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    // use Content Provider's db member variable in the following code block
    int count;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case INCIDENTS:
            count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

Then add the following finalize code to your content provider

```
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue, sorry I didn't see your comment response earlier!

Comment: Not a problem!  Thanks a lot for the help.  I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Simpler: don't ever call `db.close()`; the `ContentProvider` will be instantiated once and will go away when your process is killed, which will handle closing database connections.